# Parameterizing query says "Mixing named and unnamed parameters is not allowed."

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to parameterized my query so **instead of this code** (`This is a working code, I didn't put all the codes here because we have nothing to do with it.`)

```
MySQL_Query = "SET @row_number = 0; " _
                & "SELECT hardware_add " _
                & "FROM (" _
                    & "SELECT " _
                    & "@row_number:=@row_number + 1 AS num, " _
                    & "hardware_add AS hardware_add " _
                    & "FROM teller_info " _
                    & "WHERE status = 'Disconnected'" _
                & ") AS sub_query " _
                & "WHERE num = " & counter & ";"
    Console.WriteLine(MySQL_Query)
    Dim MySQL_CMD As New MySqlCommand(MySQL_Query, MysqlConn)

    MySQL_CMD.Connection.Open()
```

I **changed** it to this.

```
    MySQL_Query = "SET @row_number = 0; " _
                & "SELECT hardware_add " _
                & "FROM (" _
                    & "SELECT " _
                    & "@row_number:=@row_number + 1 AS num, " _
                    & "hardware_add AS hardware_add " _
                    & "FROM teller_info " _
                    & "WHERE status = 'Disconnected'" _
                & ") AS sub_query " _
                & "WHERE num = ?;"
    Console.WriteLine(MySQL_Query)
    Dim MySQL_CMD As New MySqlCommand(MySQL_Query, MysqlConn)


    MySQL_CMD.Connection.Open()
    MySQL_CMD.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("counter", counter))
```

The error says

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Mixing named and unnamed parameters is not allowed.

**My question is** how can I properly `parameterize` that query?

Comment: did you try give a name to that parameter? I mean, literal '@counter'  in both sql and mysqlparameter?

Comment: @CapitánCavernícola Thanks! I change it to this `"WHERE num = @counter;"` and `MySQL_CMD.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@counter", counter))` Sorry, I didn't know that it will make a difference. Please post an answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give a name to that param, doing so:

```
MySQL_Query = "SET @row_number = 0; " _
            & "SELECT hardware_add " _
            & "FROM (" _
                & "SELECT " _
                & "@row_number:=@row_number + 1 AS num, " _
                & "hardware_add AS hardware_add " _
                & "FROM teller_info " _
                & "WHERE status = 'Disconnected'" _
            & ") AS sub_query " _
            & "WHERE num = @counter;"
Console.WriteLine(MySQL_Query)

Dim MySQL_CMD As New MySqlCommand(MySQL_Query, MysqlConn)
MySQL_CMD.Connection.Open()
MySQL_CMD.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@counter", counter))
```